# I can't load library in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, load

I am having a problem loading library in Ruby.
I want to load gibberish, mechanize, colorize.
So I first installed the lib:

```
sudo gem install gibberish mechanize colorize
```

i got no error for this, both on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and macOS 10.14.4.

My script's content is as following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'mechanize'
require 'colorize'
require 'gibberish'
```

when i run, i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from test:3:in `<main>'
    1: from /snap/ruby/167/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/snap/ruby/167/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': cannot load such file -- mechanize (LoadError)
```

Also, when i change the order of require of library like

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'gibberish'
require 'mechanize'
require 'colorize'
```

i get error of glibberish.
How can i fix? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can follow like this.

**Step 1:** Create a folder and move to this newly created folder.

```
$ mkdir my_folder
$ cd my_folder
```

**Step 2:** Create a new `Gemfile` inside this folder and put your required gems.

```
# my_folder/Gemfile

source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "colorize"
gem "mechanize"
gem "gibberish"
```

**Step 3:** Run `bundle install` to install your required gems.

**Step 4:** Create a ruby file and put your required code inside this and run.

```
# my_folder/my_file.rb

require "mechanize"
require "colorize"
require "gibberish"

puts "Hello World"
```

To run this file file please use `ruby my_file.rb`. Thnks :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are installing the gem using `sudo` but running the script from non-sudo user. As you can see if you run `sudo gem list --local` and `gem list --local` it will give different results because gem install with `sudo` might not be available to the user.

So it's better to use a ruby version manager [rvm](https://rvm.io) or [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) which allows to have separate environment for each of your app. Or you can use `gem install --user-install <gemname>` to install the gem without sudo.